# How to get the name of the panel your JLayeredPane is on

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlayeredpane

Throughout my program, I use `JLayeredPane` a lot to layer panels. To traverse through these panels, I typically have code similar to this:

```java
jLayeredPane.removeAll();
jLayeredPane.add(jPanel4);
jLayeredPane.revalidate();
jLayeredPane.repaint();
```

In a different method, how am I able to see what panel I am on (or have added)? Would I only be able to do this with a variable indicating the panel or could I use `getLayer()` or something along those lines?

I have tried `getLayer()`, however I don't really know how to quite use it as I would not be able to do something like `jLayeredPane.getLayer(jLayeredPane);`. So how do I properly see what panel I have added to my layered pane?

Comment: Why? What is the information needed for? I suspect a possible xy-problem where the best solution is a completely different approach, to be hones.

Comment: Sounds like something `CardLayout` might be able to solve

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011324/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-panel-your-jlayeredpane-is-on#comment134060388_76011324), i.e. _Sounds like something [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) might be able to solve_

Comment: I am using cardLayout - I need this because I am reusing a class but through a different perspective - manager mode (allows access to 3 different types of accs), and staff mode (allows access to only 1 acc type (customer accounts)).

Comment: The button "add" allows me to add an account, however the button's panel is accessed through ALL of my panels (regardless of account type), including other types of accounts besides customer accs. When I press "back" from the btn "add"'s panel, it automatically brings me back to the screen where you select the acc type (which should NOT be accessed through staff). Changing it to come back to customer tab would be strange as it means that from any tab regardless of acc type, you press back and it goes to customer.

Comment: I hope this makes sense, if it does not please respond and I can add visuals